# Convergence of quadratic variation of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, quadratic-variation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F}=\{\mathcal{F}_t:t>0\},P)$ be a filtred probability space and $B=\{B_t:t>0\}$ a Brownian Motion. Say $0=t_0^k<...<t_{N_k}^k=t$ is a partition of $[0,t]$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\{\sup_{j=1,...,N_k}|t_j^k-t_{j-1}^k|\}=0$.
I'm trying to prove that: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\lVert{V_k^2(B)_t-t}\rVert_{L^2}^2=0,$$
where: $$V_k^2(B)_t=\sum_{j=1}^{N_k}(B_{t_{j}^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2,$$
and: $$\lVert{X}\rVert_{L^2}^2=E[|X|^2]=\int_{\Omega}|X|^2dP.$$
My professor wrote that $\forall{i<j}$ we have:
$$E[(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2(B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2]=\\=E\{E[(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k}](B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2\}=\\=E[(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2]\cdot{E[(B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2]},$$
but I don't get why these equations hold.

Comment: Towering property of conditional expectation and independence of increments.

Comment: @geetha290krm can you do all the math? How do you use these two properties?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not even look up the given hints.

Comment: @KurtG. I'm OP, why do you think I'm not looking up the hints? Don't you see I asked for more details? In particular I don't understand how to use tower property (and why it can be used). Independence of increments was helpful.

Comment: That's a better response than to ask instantly as it seems "can you do all the maths?". The tower property is $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[XY|{\cal F}_{t^k_{j-1}}]]\,.$ The independence of increments yields $\mathbb E[XY|{\cal F}_{t^k_{j-1}}]=\mathbb E[X|{\cal F}_{t^k_{j-1}}]Y\,.$ Do you see where your professor used those properties and what you have to put in for $X$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As "tower property" I always meant the following: given $\mathcal{G}_0\subset{G}$ where $\mathcal{G}_0$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{G}$, then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{G}_0]=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_0]$. Is this wrong or a more general case?

Comment: @KurtG. I understand why your "tower property" holds.  Now I should take $Y=(B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2$ out, but it does not seem possible since $Y\not\in{L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F_{t_{j-1}^k}},P)}$. I can't even use $X=P(X|\mathcal{G})$, where $X=(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2$, since $X\not\in{L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F_{t_{j-1}^k}},P)}$

Comment: 1. "Your" tower property is more general than "mine". Hint: what is $\mathbb E[X|{\cal G}_0]$ when ${\cal G}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ ? 2. When -as your professor assumes- $i<j$ then $i\le j-1$ and that $Y$ that you have correctly chosen is thankfully ${\cal F}_{t^k_{j-1}}$ measurable. $L^\infty$ you don't need. $L^1$ is enough. Keep pressing on !

Comment: @KurtG. I used "pulling out what is known" property, instead of independence, to show that $E[XY|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k}]=YE[X|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k}]$, I can do this since $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k}$-measurable and $XY\in{L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_{t_{j}^k},P)}$, am I right? 
Only then I used independence "to remove" $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k}$ from $E(X|\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}^k})$. Then I can take out all $E(X)$ from the external expected value

Comment: Totally right ! I realize now that due to independence of $X$ and $Y$ we could have gone directly from $E(XY)$ to $E(X)E(Y)$ without using a tower property.

Comment: @KurtG. So you're saying I could go directly from $E[(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2(B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2]$ to $E[(B_{t_j^k}-B_{t_{j-1}^k})^2]\cdot{E[(B_{t_i^k}-B_{t_{i-1}^k})^2]}$ just using the fact $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Without any other property I mentioned before?

Comment: Yes. Your professor should get that hint.